# Python wrapper for Google Maps making Google App Engine crash?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-maps

I am currently trying to build a web app using Google App Engine that will involve using the Google Maps API. Since I am coding in python, I tried importing the python wrapper for Google Maps (found [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/googlemaps/)); however, performing the import will cause my web app to crash. Are there any suggestions for how I can fix this problem? I'm guessing the crash might have something to do with the fact that I need to incorporate the google maps python wrapper into my application, but how do I go about doing that?

Thanks!

Comment: What does "crash" mean? What happens? What errors do you get?

Comment: I get a page that says "Server Error: The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost:8081/. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly."

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using it via direct webcalls if you are unable to debug the current problem?

All that wrapper would seem to do is make calls like this a little easier.

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false
```

Here's where I got that link from, plenty more info there.

http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/Using-the-Google-Maps-APIs-from-App-Engine

Comment: I was trying to avoid direct webcalls, but I guess I might need to resort to that method if I can't get the python wrapper for the API to work. Thanks for your response!